# Max(datetime_column) in a where clause

Tags: mysql, max, where-clause, prestashop

I created a query to update a field. But I need to change the value of the last record. In my **ps_order_history** table there's the **date_add** column. Its type is *datetime*. How could I get the last record if I can't use the max() function in where clause? This is what I got until now (there's some fixed parameters, but it's just to test. I'll change this in the PHP code):

```
UPDATE ps_order_history AS h 
INNER JOIN ps_order_detail d ON d.id_order = h.id_order
INNER JOIN ps_orders o ON o.id_order = h.id_order
SET h.id_order_state = 18
WHERE d.product_name = "Academia Mastermaq"

AND o.id_customer = (
SELECT id_customer
FROM ps_customer
WHERE firstname = "Cristiano"
AND lastname = "Ferreira dos Santos"
)

AND max(h.date_add)
```

Thanks.

Comment: No. I want to update only one order. The last one, associated to the date_add field.

Comment: Did you try `WHERE h.date_add=max(h.date_add)` ? 
You have two WHERE clause in your first query
`UPDATE ... WHERE o.id_consumer=(SELECT ...) WHERE ...`

Comment: I typed wrong. Actually, I've used AND, and got this error: Error Code: 1111. Invalid use of group function

Comment: Try another inner query
`AND h.date_add=(SELECT MAX(date_add) FROM ps_order_history)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it! I've discovered about variables in MySQL and used a one to store the max id_order_history (I realized I didn't need the date_add column because the max id_order_history is the last data). After, I updated the table.

This is the query:

```
SET @maxid = 
(
    SELECT max(h.id_order_history)

    FROM ps_order_history h

    WHERE h.id_order =
    (
        SELECT max(p.id_order)
        FROM ps_orders p
        INNER JOIN ps_order_detail d ON d.id_order = p.id_order

        WHERE p.id_customer = 
        (
            SELECT id_customer
            FROM ps_customer
            WHERE firstname = '$firstname'
            AND lastname = '$lastname'
            LIMIT 1
        )

        AND d.product_name = '$nome_produto'
        AND p.module = 'pagseguro'

        LIMIT 1
    )
);

UPDATE ps_order_history h
SET h.id_order_state = $status
WHERE h.id_order_history = @maxid;
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do that by using Order by xxx DESC LIMIT 1

Comment: Are you sure the order by will get the last date_add record?

**UPDATE**
The MySQL has showed me I can't user ORDER BY in a WHERE clause.

Comment: * The MySQL has showed me I can't user ORDER BY in a UPDATE clause